# Mysql,Php,Laravel checkbox error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I have the next question. How can I solve that problem? I have two tables `vehicles` and `vehicles_extras`. In the first table have a lot of columns. In the second table I have only 4 columns:

```
id, vehicle_id, vehicletype, vehicle_extra
```

The `id` is autoincrement, the `vehicle_id` is from the first table the `id` column, the 'vehicletype' is a string, type of the vehicle, the `vehicle_extra` is the number of the extras.

So I have a search form,where is the `extras` are checkboxes, `extra[]`. In a `web.php` I have this code:

```
$data1=DB::table('vehicles_extras')->where('vehicletype','$vt')->where('vehicle_extra',$extras);
```

....

```
if(Input::has('extras'))
    $query->union($data1);
$data=$query->get();
```

for that I get error:

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select count(*) as aggregate from `vm_vehicles` where `vehicletype` = car) union (select * from `vm_vehicles_extras` where `vehicletype` = car and `vehicle_extra` = 2))

But ok, let's say it's working, but I have array with more values, so I want to use `whereIn` .

Any idea? I use Laravel 5.3.

Comment: Are you trying to get all data that matches in both tables (i.e. `SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE...; SELECT * FROM vehicles_extras WHERE...`) or are you trying to get the data and match vehicles.id to vehicles_extras.vehicle_id? If it's the first, get each table separately without a where, since it sounds like you want all of the data. If it's the second, use a `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to create [`one-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relation between `vehicles` and `vehicles_extras`.

Add the following relation in your `Vehicle` model:

```
public function vehicleExtras()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\VehicleExtra');
}
```

Then you can query it as:

```
Vehicle::whereHas('vehicleExtras', function ($q) use($extra) {
    $q->where('vehicletype', 'car')
      ->whereIn('vehicle_extra', $extra);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thx,but now I get this error:
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vm_vehicles_extras.vehicle_search_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `vm_vehicles` where `vehicletype` = car and exists (select * from `vm_vehicles_extras` where `vm_vehicles_extras`.`vehicle_search_id` = `vm_vehicles`.`id` and `vehicletype` is null and `vehicle_extra` in (4)))`

Comment: The biggest problem,no idea from where is `vm_vehicles_extras.vehicle_search_id` that?

Comment: Show your table structure in your question.